# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am rying to fill a List in Flutter with some data from a JSON file.
However, my code keeps throwing the exception `"NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null."`

Where is my mistake?

JSON:

```
 {
    "#1": "6",
    "#2": null,
    "#3": null,
    "#4": null,
    "#5": null,
    "#6": null,
    
    "material_1": "stone",
    "material_2": null,
    "material_3": null,
    "material_4": null,
    "material_5": null,
    "material_6": null,
}
```

My Code:

```
List<String>getMaterialAmounts(){
    List<String> materialAmountList;
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
      materialAmountList.add(_json["#${i+1}"] ?? "-1");
    }
    return materialAmountList;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize the list first

Change

```
List<String> materialAmountList;
```

To

```
List<String> materialAmountList = new List();
```

Comment: I forget every time that a List needs an instance...

Comment: the amount of times i spent hours on that same problem haha
glad i could help